# How can I get rid of multiple "not like" clauses in my Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I'm grabbing the DDL for tables in a database.

There are externally mounted tables, temporary tables, and other tables that I don't want that information, so I have clauses like, `...where object_name not like 'ext_%'...` but I have six of those clauses.

Is there some way of combining them so that I can do something like `...where object_name not like in (EXT_%, TMP_%,...)`?

Sort of like how you can say, `...where id in (1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 4):

maybe with regexp_like
http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

something like this:

... where not regexp_like(object_name, 'EXT\.*|TMP\.*|.....')

Comment: @phileas fogg, IMHO this is the right way of doing it in Oracle, the only thing is writing the right regular expression if you'll give us the strings your looking to be like we'll hell you describe the right regexp

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
...
WHERE SUBSTR(object_name, 1, 4) NOT IN ('EXT_', 'TMP_', ...)
```

Comment: Ugh, unfortunately that's not filtering out the tables like it should.  I'm going to fiddle around with it some more because it's what I imagined a solution would look like...

Answer (score 0):

If thay are all that pattern XXX_%, you could strip the first four chars and use not in('EXT_','TMP_'

Or perhapos have a wee table with them in and do an outer join.

Another option maybe would be

Not Like '[ET][XM][TP]_%'
not very readable that though.

PS presumably you are escaping underscore seeing as it's any single character.